Solicitudes POST no funcionan con Ngrok
Estoy usando Ngrok para probar un servicio web que estoy desarrollando en Django. El problema que encuentro es que las solicitudes POST que estoy realizando desde JavaScript no funcionan salvo que esté en local. La solicitudes marcan una respuesta 200 OK pero devuelven null en vez de la información requerida, incluso en el log de mi terminal no se ve nada de la información (estoy imprimiendo las respuestas json antes de devolverals).
Además de esto, me encuentro con el problema de que la solicitudes solo funcionan cuando la conexión se hace desde la misma red. Si se accede desde otra, me envían errores de CONNECTION_REFUSED.
Esta es la forma en la que estoy haciendo las solicitudes con JavaScript
const url = 'http://localhost:8000/register_equipment/';

const data = {
    "product": inputProduct.value,
    "description": inputDescription.value,
    "serial": inputSerial.value,
    "warehouse_location": inputWarehouseLocation.value,
    "shelf_location": inputShelfLocation.value,
    "additional_location": inputAdditionalLocation.value,
    "observations": inputObservations.value,
    "quantity": inputQuantity.value,
    "dedicated": dedicatedValues
};

// Request configuration
const options = {
    method: 'POST',
    mode: 'cors',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'X-CSRFToken': getCookie('csrftoken') // Add CSRF token header
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(data)
};

// Perform the request using fetch
fetch(url, options)
    .then(response => {
        if (response.ok) {
            return response.json(); // Convert the response to JSON
        }
        throw new Error('Request failed');
    })
    .then(responseData => {
        console.log(responseData.groups); // Handle response data
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error fetching group list:', error); // Handle errors
    });

This is the function I'm using to retreive the CSRF Token

function getCookie(name) {
    let cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
        const cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (let i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            const cookie = cookies[i].trim();
            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cookieValue;
}

Y esta es la vista a la que se hace la solicitud en el backend.
@csrf_exempt
def register_equipment(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('login')
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Get JSON data from the frontend
        data = json.loads(request.body)
        print(data)
        print(data.get("dedicated"))

        # Process location data
        location = {
            "warehouse": data.get("warehouse_location"),
            "shelf": data.get("shelf_location"),
            "additional": data.get("additional_location"),
        }

        # Process incoming data and save the equipment
        try:
            new_equipment = Equipment(
                product=data.get("product"),
                description=data.get("description"),
                serial=data.get("serial"),
                location=location,
                observations=data.get("observations"),
                dedicated=data.get("dedicated"),
                quantity=data.get("quantity"),
                available=True
            )
            new_equipment.save()
            response_data = {'message': 'Equipment registered successfully'}
            return JsonResponse(response_data)

        except KeyError:
            return JsonResponse({'error': 'Missing required data'}, status=400)
    
    return JsonResponse({'error': 'Failed to register equipment'}, status=400)

Intenté seguir la documentación para instalar el CORS middleware pero tampoco funcionó
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    "corsheaders",  
    ...
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    ...
    "corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware",
    ...
]

Lo que no entiendo es que cuando las solicitudes POST se hacen por medio de formularios, estas si funcionan (como en el caso de mi login), por lo que no sé si el problema está en mis solicitudes de JavaScript.
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="username">Nombre de usuario:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" id="username" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password">Contraseña:</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="password" required>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Iniciar sesión</button>
                            
</form>

La verdad me encuentro algo desesperado, cualquier ayuda se agradecería muchísimo.
